# IFTTT doesn't trigger on new row for Google Sheets service

Tags: google-sheets, ifttt

I'm creating an Applet that will trigger as follows:

> If New row added to, then Send an email from myemail@gmail.com

This is Applet version ID 100348625.

Notice the "to," which sounds to me like a bug. I've verified that everything is done properly and still this applet is never triggered. I'm adding rows to the spreadsheet and nothing happens. The applet says "Never run" so it doesn't even attempt to do it. It's like the adding of the row isn't being detected by IFTTT.

The spreadsheet contains an email address for the destination. The body of the email is long but within the maximum. I'm connected to my Google account for both the Google Sheet and Gmail services. My spreadsheet URL is good. I've tried both the internal URL and the Shared URL. I've also tried with the path and name instead of the URL but the same result.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's not that hard to create a trigger in [tag:google-apps-script] to send a email.

Comment: @TheMaster Yes I've considered that but I'm planning to do a whole lot of integration work and this is just the first step. But otherwise this would be a worthy solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I replicated your issue and I have managed to find a workaround, using Mail, instead of Gmail. When using the Gmail as `that` I got exactly the same result as yours - my applet was never triggered. Then I did it anew with Mail as `that`, and it started to trigger right away, sending me a bunch of notifications on each edit/row added. But the emails I receive are from "*Google Sheets via IFTTT*" which is *action@ifttt.com* instead of my own email.

Then I figured that something is probably wrong with the service and I headed to the services outage page of IFTTT which is [located here](https://status.ifttt.com/?utm_medium=Help&utm_source=Applets&utm_campaign=Current_Service_Outages&utm_term=&utm_content=). As of the time of this answer, one of the issues states:

> Gmail actions may fail for some users Incident Report for IFTTT
>
> Identified
>
> The issue has been identified and a fix is being worked on.
>   It will require a large rework in how Gmail is implemented, we
>   appreciate your patience as we get Gmail up and running for everyone.
>   (Posted May 15, 2019 - 16:51 PDT)

This sounds to me like a serious issue, that is probably the explanation of all your trouble. It probably fails silently in the background and it the whole applet never registers as triggered.

Until they've fixed it, I suggest using Mail, instead of Gmail.

Here is how my working version looks:

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: The issue with this solution is that the email address for the destination is in the spreadsheet. In other words, I need to send the email FROM this email account and NOT TO it...

Comment: That said, it seems that you are correct about the cause of the problem. Thanks!

Comment: @Emmanuel Glad to be able to help! Yes, it seems we found the problem, but I’m afraid that there is no workaround at this time that fits your use case. Besides, have you considered the option to use the “Office 365 Mail” action and their mail address as your from if this is acceptable? But again, it won’t work with that particular gmail account... The last option is to integrate and script things by yourself, through the available APIs, but that would be quite a bit of effort compared to IFTTT. Or just wait for them to fix it :)

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I had to switch to another solution than IFTTT because this bug is not going to be fixed soon enough. Until it is fixed, I have no choice.

So I went with [Integromat](https://integromat.com) and I was able to do my integration work easily.

Comment: Nice find. Never knew about Integromat!